# Get multi data from one entity with one method

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

How I can get multiple data from entity data row

```
 public function findByUser1Id($userId)
       {
           $connections = $this->_em
               ->getRepository('AppBundle:ConnectionsList')
               ->findBy(array('user1Id' => $userId));

           foreach($connections as $con)
           {
               $user = $this->_em
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
                   ->findOneBy(array('id' => $con->getUser2Id()));

               var_dump($user->getFirstname());
               var_dump($user->getLastname());
               var_dump($user->getEmail());
               var_dump($user->getId());
               die;
           }
       }
```

I need some way to get data in one row in example:

```
$user->get(array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email' ...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, but can't get all data in one row

code is here:

```
public function findByUser1Id($userId)
       {
           $connections = $this->_em
               ->getRepository('AppBundle:ConnectionsList')
               ->findBy(array('user1Id' => $userId));

           foreach($connections as $con)
           {
               $user = $this->_em
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
                   ->findOneBy(array('id' => $con->getUser2Id()));

               array_push($user, array(
                          'id' => $data->getId(),
                          'email'=>$data->getEmail(),
                          'firstname'=>$data->getFirstname(),
                          'lastname'=>$data->getLastname()  
                         ));
            }
            return $data
       }
```